# How to access sub-level object data through function?

Tags: javascript, function, sorting, object

I have an array "projectList" that i'm sorting with following function.

```
sort(key) {
  this.projectsList.sort((a, b) => (a[key] > b[key] ? 1 : -1))
}
```

When calling function, lets say `sort('title')`, it sorts the projects by title. All works fine.

Some of the keys that i need to sort by are deeper inside my array object. Normaly i'd access the value by `this.projectsList.taxonomies.project-type.name`

How do i pass the "project-type.name" value to sort function so i could sort the array by it?

Comment: Pass a callback function that can do whatever it wants, instead of a property name

Comment: Care to give an example?

Comment: `sort(x => x.title)`

Comment: Works wonders! Thank you.